# Get the id of the stored items after using Laravel insert eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I stored an array in the database using the `Laravel` insert Eloquent method as below:

```
$newTags = [
    [
        'name' => 'tag1'
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'tag2'
    ],
];

if (sizeof($newTags) > 0) {
    Tag::insert($newTags);
}
```

After that, is there a way to get the `id` of the saved items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For bulk insertion there's no built in method to get inserted IDs. You can use foreach loop to insert one by one and get the IDs using `insertGetId` and put them into an array.

```
$insertedIDs = [];
if (count($newTags) > 0) {
    foreach ($newTags as $newTag) {
        $insertedIDs[] = Tag::insertGetId($newTag);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this,

```
$newTags = [
        [
            'name' => 'tag1'
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'tag2'
        ],
    ];

    if(count($newTags) > 0){
         $id = Tag::insertGetId($newTags);
    }
```